# Removing duplicate rows in a dataframe with some conditions on data in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe, df

```
Index   time   block   cell
 0       9      25      c1
 1       9      25      c1
 2       33     35      c2
 3       47     4       c1
 4       47     17      c2
 5       100    21      c1
 6       120    21      c1
 7       120    36      c2
```

The duplicates are to be dropped based on time column. However, there is a condition:
- if two or more similar times have the same cells, for example, index 0 and index 1 have c1
  then keep any of the columns.
- if two or more similar times have different cells eg index 3 and 4 and index 6 and 7 then keep all the rows corresponding to duplicate times

The resulting data frame will be as follows: df_result =

```
Index   time   block   cell
 0       9      25      c1
 2       33     35      c2
 3       47     4       c1
 4       47     17      c2
 5       100    21      c1
 6       120    21      c1
 7       120    36      c2
```

Tried 
 `df.drop_duplicates('time')`

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['time', 'cell'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by binning the original DataFrame into categories and then running `drop_duplicates()` within each category.

```python3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[9,9,33,47,47,100,120,120],'block':[25,25,35,4,17,21,21,36],'cell':'c1;c1;c2;c1;c2;c1;c1;c2'.split(';')})

categories = df['cell'].astype('category').unique()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for category in categories:
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, df[df['cell'] == category].drop_duplicates(keep='first')])

df2 = df2.sort_index()
```

This will result in `df2` being

```
    time  block cell
0     9     25   c1
2    33     35   c2
3    47      4   c1
4    47     17   c2
5   100     21   c1
6   120     21   c1
7   120     36   c2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by one of the desired columns, then drop the duplicates on the other column as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[9,9,33,47,47,100,120,120],'block':[25,25,35,4,17,21,21,36],'cell': ['c1','c1','c2','c1','c2','c1','c1','c2']})
grouped = df.groupby('time')
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[] ,'block':[],'cell':[]})
for ind, gr in grouped:
    final_df = final_df.append(gr.drop_duplicates("cell"))
```